# Custom django registration form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-registration

I am trying to customize the Django registration form.  I have `mysite` project in which I have created `registration1` app.

**mysite/registration1/forms.py**

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from django import forms
class UserRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    unique_id = forms.CharField(min_length=12,max_length=12,label=("Unique id"))
```

**mysite/regbackend.py**

```
import profile
from registration1.forms import UserRegistrationForm
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.sites.models import RequestSite
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

from registration import signals
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from registration.models import RegistrationProfile

class MyBackend(object):

   def register(self, request, **kwargs):
        username, email, password = kwargs['username'],kwargs['email'], kwargs['password1']
        if Site._meta.installed:
        site = Site.objects.get_current()
        else:
            site = RequestSite(request)
        new_user = RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(username, email,
                                                                password, site)
        signals.user_registered.send(sender=self.__class__,
                                 user=new_user,
                                 request=request)
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        user.unique_id=kwargs['unique_id']
        address_user = Address()
        address_user.save()
        contact_user = Contact(address=address_user,email=user.email)
        contact_user.save()

        address_company = Address()
        address_company.save()
        contact_company = Contact(address=address_company)
        contact_company.save()
        company = Company(contact=contact_company, admin=user)
        company.save()
        user_profile = UserProfile(user=user,contact=contact_user,position='',company=company  )
    user_profile.save()
    user.save()

        return new_user
```

**mysite/urls.py**

```
from registration.views import register
import registration.backends.default.urls as regUrls
import mysite.regbackend
from registration1.forms import UserRegistrationForm
url(r'^accounts/register/$', register,{'backend':'mysite.regbackend.MyBackend','form_class': UserRegistrationForm},name='registration_register'),
```

**But this is giving me error**

```
'MyBackend' object has no attribute 'registration_allowed'
```

I also want to replace username in original Django registration form with unique_id which is entered by user?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? Do you just want to be able to add extra information to a user profile at the time of registration?

Comment: yes i want to add extra information during registration and also delete that username field

Answer (score 6):

I suggest to you to inherit and override some methods using any of two default backends:

```
....
from registration.backends.default import SimpleBackend
class MyBackend(SimpleBackend):
   ....
```

or if you need backend with email confirmation:

```
....
from registration.backends.default import DefaultBackend
class MyBackend(DefaultBackend):
   ....
```

Comment: Do you think it can be an answer on your question? Could you mark in this case?